# Start a module at startup on gentoo

Tags: boot, gentoo, kernel-module

I use gentoo.
I have a module nammed "cgosdrv" (for instance).
I can launch it without problem with "modprobe cgosdrv" (as root)

I want to start it automatically at startup, so I add to /etc/conf.d/modules

To do that on ubuntu, we just add the module name in the file, but doing so on gentoo, generate an error: "error loading /etc/conf.d/modules".
(and the module isn't loaded)

What is the correct syntax to just simply load a module without any parameters from "/etc/conf.d/modules" ?

Comment: try adding a file `cgosdrv` containing a single line `cgosdrv` in `/etc/modutils` and run `update-modules` as root.

Comment: Sorry, the folder /etc/modutils doesn't exists in my gentoo. Looks bad...

Answer (score 1):

In fact it was simple, though not very intuitive:

at the end of /etc/conf.d/modules, I just add this line:

```
modules="cgosdrv"
```

And that's fine.